# Why did the makers of the Pi have an entirely new game made (minecraft-pi)?

Tags: minecraft, open-source, games

`minecraft-pi` comes with the free Raspbian OS, i.e. is free. Minecraft is *not* an open source game, and is quite probably a trademark.

what I would like to know, is why they made a new, non-open-source game, when there is a perfectly usable similar open-source program, **Minetest**.

Answer (score 1):

minecraft-pi may be provided free of charge, but it's not in any way free or open source. Here's the minimal licence provided with the distribution (in `/usr/share/doc/minecraft-pi/LICENSE.txt`):

> *** The real license isn't finished yet, here's what goes in plain english ***
>
> You may execute the minecraft-pi binary on a Raspberry Pi or an emulator
>
> You may use any of the source code included in the distribution for any purpose (except evil)
>
> You may not redistribute any modified binary parts of the distribution

minecraft-pi was [written by Mojang](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/minecraft-its-here/), so it uses the company's intellectual property.

Comment: my question is why they didn't use a 100% open-source one.

Comment: because the Foundation made a deal with Mojang to provide the real one. Not everything in Raspbian is open source: Mathematica absolutely isn't.